# Prevent user from directly accessing URL in React application?

Tags: reactjs, url

Is there a way to stop the user from directly accessing a URL on my application? For example, we have a page that is accessed as localhost:3000/scheduling but I want to re-route back to the homepage. I couldn't find many helpful articles that could achieve this. I am using React by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in many ways, this is just an example :

```
  const location = useLocation();
  let history = useHistory();

  if(location.state == undefined || location.state == null || location.state == ''){
  history.push("/");   
  }
```

'/' is by default your home page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true
    setTimeout(cb, 100)
  },
  signout(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = false
    setTimeout(cb, 100)
  }
}

const Public = () => <h3>Public</h3>
const Protected = () => <h3>Protected</h3>

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirectToReferrer: false
  }
  login = () => {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
      this.setState(() => ({
        redirectToReferrer: true
      }))
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } }
    const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state

    if (redirectToReferrer === true) {
      return <Redirect to={from} />
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>You must log in to view the page</p>
        <button onClick={this.login}>Log in</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
  )} />
)

export default function AuthExample () {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/public">Public Page</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <Route path="/public" component={Public}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <PrivateRoute path='/protected' component={Protected} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

[Source](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

We can use **Conditional rendering** tracing the **history**.

You can also add conditions using `this.props.history.location.key` or `this.props.history.action`

1. Key exists and action is 'PUSH' when we redirect user using  `this.props.history.push`
2. Key property doesn't exist and action is 'POP' when a user tries to access the URL directly

`return this.props.history.location.key ? (<div></div>) : null`